# how to use group by clause in ssp.class.php of datatables

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

The sql should be

```
select max(id),Staff_name from position group by Staff_name
```

I modify the `ssp.class.php`.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".implode(", ", self::pluck($columns, 'db'))."
FROM $table
$where
$order
$limit group by Staff_name.
```

However, it dose not work. How to realize this sql?

Comment: What does not work? What is the error message? How do you apply the query? What else should we guess?